# PyDev: chaco.shell import

Tags: python, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I have two workspaces with identical code and sys.path working on a Mac.   One works fine, the other has problems importing chaco.shell (ImportError: No module named shell).

I'm using the enthought distribution.  Neither workspace has chaco as builtin.

What could be the problem?

Here is the code:

```
    import sys
    from pprint import pprint as pp
    pp(sys.path)


    import numpy as np
    from chaco.shell import *


    x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)

    plot(x, y, "r-")
    title("First plot")
    ytitle("sin(x)")
    show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing all other python files in the directory containing the code in question.  Seems like when python runs a py file, other py and pyc files in the same directory can interfere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. with the code:

```
import numpy as np
from chaco.shell import *

x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plot(x, y, "r-")
title("First plot")
ytitle("sin(x)")
show()
```

the same error as you. And i realise that i named my python file chaco.py and it create a chaco.pyc which was the problem. I rename my file something else and it worked perfectly.